# Has Chrome's temporary "Lax + POST" behaviour been removed?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, samesite

I am troubleshooting a bug that involves a cookie that is *sometimes* missing from a cross-site POST request.

This [page from The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/) (last updated Mar 18, 2021) describes a temporary intervention to SameSite cookie behaviour, whereby some cookies have a 2-minute window for certain top-level cross-site POST requests.

It is referred to as "Lax+POST".

It describes that this behaviour as a temporary intervention which would be removed.
I cannot find any reference that says it has been removed, nor any updates within the last year.

Is this 2-minute behaviour still in place today (Dec 16, 2022) ?

Comment: What makes you think this behaviour has been removed? I would be very surprised if it had been removed without any announcement by the Chromium team. Empirical data indicates that it hasn't. Try running https://samesitetest.com/ in your Chromium instance.

Comment: @jub0bs Probably my misunderstanding as I learn about it. Posts from more than a year ago said that it was a temporary feature, and I could only find information about it in deeper technical sources. Many sources of information about SameSite do not mention "Lax+POST", "Lax-Allowing-Unsafe", or the differences between Lax and Lax-by-default. So I found it difficult to determine the current status of that feature.

Comment: @jub0bs I've learned a lot in the 2 days since asked this question! I would accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: The issue I had was that I needed some assurance that the information I read was still current. I have subscribed to get updates on features that I'm interested in at https://chromestatus.com/myfeatures , and this gives me the assurance that I need that there have been no recent changes.

Comment: Not sure you should rely on this behaviour. It was only implemented to ease the transition to `SameSite=Lax` by default. Not all browsers implement or plan to implement it.